# Convert 3D Tensor to 4D Tensor in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I had difficulty finding information on reshaping in PyTorch. Tensorflow is quite easy.

My tensor has shape `torch.Size([3, 480, 480])`.
I want to convert it to a 4D tensor with shape [1,3,480,480].
How do I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`unsqueeze()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze)

For example:

```
x = torch.zeros((4,4,4))   # Create 3D tensor 
x = x.unsqueeze(0)         # Add dimension as the first axis (1,4,4,4)
```

I've seen a few people use indexing with `None` to add a singular dimension as well. For example:

```
x = torch.zeros((4,4,4))   # Create 3D tensor 
print(x[None].shape)       #  (1,4,4,4)
print(x[:,None,:,:].shape) #  (4,1,4,4)
print(x[:,:,None,:].shape) #  (4,4,1,4)
print(x[:,:,:,None].shape) #  (4,4,4,1)
```

Personally, I prefer `unsqueeze()`, but it's good to be familiar with both.

Comment: API names are anyhow given.